# Syntax error when trying to assign objects to class in Python using Mac OS X Terminal

Tags: python, class, object, terminal

I am learning python programming and I am just going through easy exercises.  One of them has me create a class as follows:

```
class MyFirstClass:
    Pass
```

That is it.  I save this and then when I try to import the file using python3.3 in a Mac Terminal and assign an object:

```
a = MyFirstClass()
```

I get a syntax error.  Am I not running the program correctly?  I have performed this task in IDLE but it does not seem to work when I am using Python in the terminal.

Comment: When I am creating it I am actually putting the "pass" line below and indented.  Did not check to make sure it would display properly on the forum.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the error text that you get? Could you post that as well?

Comment: ok so i think it is more of my ignorance in not understanding the difference between running code and importing code.  I can import my file with the code into a python session in the terminal but then when I try to assign an object to the MyFirstClass class i actually get a name error: NameError: name 'MyFirstClass' is not defined.  The same happens in IDLE when I just import the code the object assignment doesn't work.  I actually have to "run" the code.  I am having trouble understanding the difference.

Answer (score 4):

Python is case-sensitive.  `Pass` should be `pass`.

Comment: Yes.  I meant to type pass in the first question.  Everything works when using IDLE with the module window open and then choosing "Run".  How does that process work when I am using Python in the Terminal?